# Got run time error in parsing javascript using while controller (got only one request, need 5 requests in view results tree)

Tags: jmeter

[image: i need 5 requests like belowe mentioned screenshot][image: got only one request in view results tree needed 5 requests as mentioned in while controller code]
 i need 5 requests as like in l'st screenshot by using code without error pls suggest

I got only one request in view results tree needed 5 requests as mentioned in while controller code in 2 nd screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I think your script **works as expected** and it stops due to 1st clause is **being met**, to wit `${titleresponse}` variable value becomes `Top 17 Appium Interview Questions` so JMeter exists the loop.

If you don't like the error in the log you can amend the second part of your condition to look like `"${counter_value}" != "5"`

Full condition just in case:

```
${__javaScript(("${titleresponse}".indexOf("Top 17 Appium Interview Questions") == -1 && "${counter_value}" != "5"),)}
```

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) language or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) for scripting so you might want to convert your expression to something like:

```
${__groovy(!vars.get('titleresponse').equals('Top 17 Appium Interview Questions') && !vars.get('counter_value').equals('5'),)}
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Tq for ur guidence but am getting only one http reqst .As mentioned in while controller  "5" it should come 5 http request after applying ur code am getting one request withut error need 5 requests. pls suggest@Dmitri